# How to convert the image format upon upload in django

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I am driving myself crazy trying to get this to work with Pillow. Here's what I have in the view.

```
new_business = form.save(request.user, commit=False)
if 'image' in request.FILES:
   from PIL import Image           
   img = Image.open(form.cleaned_data['image'])
   if img.mode != "RGB":
       img = img.convert("RGB")
   filename = str(new_business.image)
   filename = filename.rsplit(".", 1)[0]
   filename = filename + '.jpg'
   img.save(filename)

   from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
   djangofile = ContentFile(img.tobytes())
   new_business.image.save(filename, djangofile)   

new_business.save()   
state = 'Service Business changes were successful.'
```

new_business.image is an ImageField. This will save a file with a .jpg in the apprpriate folder, but it is a corrupted file!

Comment: close opened file after save() like `img.close()` .

Comment: close() just gave me an attribute error

Comment: paste traceback here . what error its displaying.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/D4xM6L57

Comment: Update code here after putting `close` in your question . may be its at wrong place .

Comment: I just checked the pillow docs at http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html, there is no close() method, are you sure? i put it right after save()

Comment: Well , if you are opening file then you have to close file . then write operation will complete . otherwise file will be corrupt .

Comment: @PriyankPatel Super-late reply but... This isn't a `file`, it's an PIL-type `Image`. It reads into memory on creation. It isn't written until you call `.save()`. There isn't a lingering `file` handle in the background.